# Chemical inventory program written in Java code won't work

Tags: java

So I have been trying to figure out how to do this for a week now. I am behind in the class due to an accident at work so I have not been participating. I started a chemical inventory program using net-beans IDE and have several errors which I don't understand? The teacher is no help and I've read and viewed video on the subject to no avail. Can some one look at my code and tell me what is wrong please. Below is my code now be gentle as I am VERY new to this. Any help would be appreciated. And this is my first post. Below the code is the requirement for week 4. Thanks in advance!

```
package chemical.inventory;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Chris
 */
public class ChemicalInventory {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        Chemical[] chemical;
        chemical = new Chemical[4];

        chemical[0] = new Chemical("Sodium Hypochlorite","1084","1.29","5000");
        chemical[1] = new Chemical("Caustic Soda","2010","1.25","5000");        
        chemical[2] = new Chemical("Sulfuric Acid","1098","2.10","3000");
        chemical[3] = new Chemical("Lime","1010","0.93","2500");


        double chemicalValue = 0.0;
        System.out.printf("\nInventory value is: $%,2f\n",chemicalValue);
    }   
    private static class Chemical {
        private String sodium_Hypochlorite;

        public Chemical() {
        }

        private Chemical(String sodium_Hypochlorite, String string, String string0, String string1) {
            this.sodium_Hypochlorite = sodium_Hypochlorite;

        }
    }
}

class Chemical.Inventory
{
    protected String chemicalName;
    protected double chemicalPrice;
    protected double chemicalStock;
    protected double chemicalitemNumber;

        public ChemicalInventory(String name, double price, double stock, double itemNumber);
        static {
        String name;
            this.chemicalTitle = title;
        double price = 0;
            this.chemicalPrice = price;
        double stock = 0;
            this.chemicalStock = stock;
            double itemNumber = 0;
            this.chemicalitemNumber = itemNumber;
    }

    Chemical(String string, String string0, String string1, String string2) {

    }
     public void setChemicalName(String name)
    {
        this.chemicalName = name;
    }
    public String getChemicalName()
    {
        return chemicalName;
    }

    public void setChemicalPrice(double price)
    {
        this.chemicalPrice = price;
    }
    public double getChemicalPrice()
    {
        return chemicalPrice;
    }

    public void setChemicalStock(double stock)
    {
        this.chemicalStock = stock;
    }
    public double getChemicalStock()
    {
        return chemicalStock;
    }

    public void setChemicalitemNumber(double itemNumber)
    {
        this.chemicalitemNumber = itemNumber;
    }
    public double getChemicalitemNumber()
    {
        return chemicalitemNumber;
    }

    public double getValue()
    {
        return this.chemicalStock * this.chemicalPrice;
    }
    static {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println( "Chemical Name:" + chemical.getChemicalTitle());
    System.out.println("Chemical Price:" + chemical.getChemicalPrice());
    System.out.println("Chemical gallons in stock:" + chemical.getChemicalStock());


    }
```

Modify the Inventory Program to use a GUI. The GUI should display the information one product at a time, including the item number, the name of the product, the number of units in stock, the price of each unit, and the value of the inventory of that product. In addition, the GUI should display the value of the entire inventory, the additional attribute, and the restocking fee.

Modify the Inventory Program by adding a button to the GUI that allows the user to move to the first item, the previous item, the next item, and the last item in the inventory. If the first item is displayed and the user clicks on the Previous button, the last item should display. If the last item is displayed and the user clicks on the Next button, the first item should display.

Add a company logo to the GUI using Java™ graphics classes.

Comment: So what are the errors, and what don't you understand about them? It would be better if you'd stop coding as soon as you receive an error you don't understand, and resolve *that* (posting a short but complete program which *just* demonstrates that problem) before continuing, rather than writing a lot of code and ending up with a lot of errors.

Comment: You public class is called `ChemicalInventory`, but you also have a second class called `Chemical.Inventory`, which has a constructor called `ChemicalInventory` and another called `Chemical`. Well, a class cannot have a period in it's name, you can't have two classes with the same name (assuming you remove the period), and the constructors must be called the same as the class, and the first constructor doesn't have a body. Just to get started.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with your code, a lot:

1. You defined `Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);` and you never use it
2. Naming convention, field `String sodium_Hypochlorite;` i believe should be named `name`
3. class `Chemical.Inventory` dot is invalid character for names in java. If you want define your class to be inner class of other class, place it there, if you want it to be on some path, use packages.
4. constructor defined in class  `class Chemical.Inventory` first does not have a body
5. Both constructors defined in class `Chemical.Inventory` has not matching names with class.
6. your first static initializer in class `Chemical.Inventory` is using `this` and some undefined variables. Logic from that block should be declared in constructor.
7. your second static initializer in class `Chemical.Inventory` is using variable `chemical` which wasnt defined anywhere.